# C# Find Winner for Connect 4 using Interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, interface

I'm currently working on an assignment to create a game of Connect 4 on a standard 7x6 grid using Visual Studio forms. I've searched on here already, but couldn't find a question that uses the same method of checking for a win that I am supposed to. I already have the architecture of the game completed; the board is fully functional, the pieces drop correctly, and already placed pieces can't be overwritten. However the catch of the assignment is that checking for a winner needs to implement an interface. This is the interface that's required:

```
interface Winner
{
    //find winner in the specified direction starting from (c,r)
    bool straightup(int c, int r);
    bool straightdown(int c, int r);
    bool left(int c, int r);
    bool right(int c, int r);
    bool diagleftup(int c, int r);
    bool diagrightdown(int c, int r);
    bool diagleftdown(int c, int r);
    bool diagrightup(int c, int r);

    //return true if there is winner
    bool winner();
}
```

Here's the code for the board if it's needed:

```
    bool isWinner, xTurn; //Keeps track if there is a winner and whose turn it is
    int xWins, oWins; //Keeps track of each players' wins
    //Keeps track of which row the next piece in the column will drop
    int col1Drop, col2Drop, col3Drop, col4Drop, col5Drop, col6Drop, col7Drop; 
    Button[,] places; //Array of buttons on the board

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        isWinner = false;
        xTurn = true;
        xWins = 0;
        oWins = 0;
        col1Drop = 0; col2Drop = 0; col3Drop = 0; col4Drop = 0; col5Drop = 0; col6Drop = 0; col7Drop = 0;
        currentTurn.Text = "X";
        winRecords.Text = "Record:" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "X Wins - 0"+ Environment.NewLine + "O Wins - 0";
        //Initializes the array of buttons on the board, starting from left to right, bottom to top
        places = new Button[,]{ { col1row1, col1row2, col1row3, col1row4, col1row5, col1row6 }, { col2row1, col2row2, col2row3, col2row4, col2row5, col2row6 }, { col3row1, col3row2, col3row3, col3row4, col3row5, col3row6 }, { col4row1, col4row2, col4row3, col4row4, col4row5, col4row6 }, { col5row1, col5row2, col5row3, col5row4, col5row5, col5row6 }, { col6row1, col6row2, col6row3, col6row4, col6row5, col6row6 }, { col7row1, col7row2, col7row3, col7row4, col7row5, col7row6 } };
    }

    private void col1row6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Runs when top button on column is clicked, all other buttons in column are disabled
    {
        if(xTurn) //Plays if its X's turn
        {
            if (col1Drop < 6) //Places piece as long as there's still a spot available 
            {
                places[0, col1Drop].BackgroundImage = GUI_Connect4.Properties.Resources.X;
                places[0, col1Drop].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch; //Fills the next available row in the column
                xTurn = false; //Changes it to next player's turn
                currentTurn.Text = "O";
                col1Drop++; //Moves to next avaiable column
            }
        }
        else //Plays if it's O's turn
        {
            if (col1Drop < 6)
            {
                places[0, col1Drop].BackgroundImage = GUI_Connect4.Properties.Resources.O;
                places[0, col1Drop].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                xTurn = true;
                currentTurn.Text = "X";
                col1Drop++;
            }
        }
    } //This code is the same for each column, with values changed accordingly
```

How would I go about checking for a win, and where should the interface be implemented? I'm assuming it should just be implemented in a separate checkWinner method that runs whenever a piece is played.

Comment: As the interface description is suggesting: Start at `(c,r)` and look at `(c+dc,r+rd)`, `(c+2*dc,r+2*dr)`, and `(c+3*dc,r+3*dr)`. There are 8 possible selections from `{-1, 0, +1}` for `dc` and `dr` depending on the direction of search. Beware of points outside the playground.

Comment: "where should the interface be implemented?"  Only a CLASS can [Implement an Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/).  So your `Connect4` class should...whoops, you don't have one of those.  In that case, your `Form1` will need to implement the `Winner` interface.

Comment: "How would I go about checking for a win" After a piece is dropped, you would call the `winner` method to see if there is a winner.  The `winner` method would presumably use all of those other methods listed in the `Winner` interface to see if there is a win condition in that particular direction.  You'll have to come up with a good way to determine a reasonable "start position / (c, r)" based on where the last piece was dropped.

Comment: @Idle_Mind A `struct` can also implement interfaces.